# How to use the GetComponent-syntax

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Im trying to understand GetComponent, but Im having a hard time figuring how to write the syntax. I got two scripts ( SpawnBehaviour and SpotClicked) and want to get the bool from "SpawnBehaviour into SpotClicked.

How do I get the syntax right, and change the boolean in SpawnBehaviour to true?

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
      screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
      offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));

    if(this.gameObject.tag == "fishSpot"){
          Debug.Log("Clicked "+gameObject.name);
          //get "stopped"bool from "SpawnBehaviour" script and set it to true
          SpawnBehaviour sb = spawnPoint.GetComponent<SpawnBehaviour>().stoppedSpawn=true;
    }
}
```

In SpawnBehaviour.cs I have got

```
public bool stoppedSpawn = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) doesn't show you an example in C#, but it's pretty straight forward.

What you'd end up doing is something like

```
SpawnBehavior sb = gameObject.GetComponent<SpawnBehaviour>();
SpotClicked sc = gameObject.GetComponent<SpotClicked>();
//Do whatever you want with the variables from either MonoBehaviour
```

There is also [the non-generic version](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/GenericFunctions.html)

```
SpawnBehaviour sb = (SpawnBehaviour) gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(SpawnBehaviour));
```

but hey, if you can save some keystrokes and casts, why not.

Of course you could cache those components in your `Start()`, if you're going to access them multiple times anyway. Calling GetComponent is expensive, particularly if you end up doing it every frame for example.

And if you subsequently want to set a boolean variable to true for SpawnBehaviour, you'd do

```
SpawnBehaviour sb = gameObject.GetComponent<SpawnBehaviour>();
sb.stoppedSpawn = true;
```

or if you don't care to keep the SpawnBehaviour around, you can do

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SpawnBehaviour>().stoppedSpawn = true;
```

But if you need it anywhere else, or need it often, do cache it.

Comment: I keep getting "Cannot implicitly type 'bool' to 'spawnBehaviour'

Comment: So show me the code you're using. Edit it into your question.

Comment: Updated my answer @Eyrik. You can't do that double-assignment deal you're trying to do. You end up assigning a boolean value to the SpawnBehaviour, which is what it complains about. Do it in two steps as above and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks so much. 
Now ill be able to continue :D

Comment: One question more: I got a looping script that spawns object as long as stoppedSpawn is false.
When i click the object, the script turns the boolean to false, but afterwards it turns straight to true again, without me having any script saying that it shall turn stoppedSpawn back to true.

Comment: Something must be changing it. Are you sure you're looking at the correct component, and not at another one that's still initialized to `public bool stoppedSpawn = false;`?

Comment: Only got 2 objects and 2 gameobjects that contain scripts. 
And nothing looks like they shall change it to false

Comment: That's going to be difficult to solve here in the comments. If you can narrow it down to a clear question (but that might involve some debugging on your behalf to have something left we can answer) perhaps try that.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, you should first understand what is a component, and what is a gameobject, then it is not hard to get the syntax right:

[image]

For instance:

```
var layer = someGameObject.GetComponent<GUILayer>();
```